# Why can't i toggle between my sidebar and navbar?

Tags: javascript, toggle, addeventlistener, sidebar

I'm making a sidebar slider on the left but it doesn't work. I don't know if it's because my codes is missing something or wrong somewhere...it'd nice of you to help completing my codes! Thank you so much!

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/48a972c999.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <i class="fas fa-bars" onclick="active()"></i>
        <div class="sidebar">
            <i class="fas fa-times" onclick="active()"></i>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my css:

```
.navbar {
    background-color: greenyellow;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

.sidebar {
    background-color: greenyellow;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 300px;
    left: -100%;
}

.sidebar.active {
    background-color: greenyellow;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 300px;
    left: 0;
}
```

This is my JS:

```
const navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar')
const sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar')

function active() {
    navbar.addEventListener('click', () => {
        navbar.classList.toggle('active')
        sidebar.classList.toggle('active')
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** You should use `addEventListener` instead of `onClick`.

**2)** If you want the navbar to slide from left so make it initially at `left: -100%` and after the button is clicked then make `left: 0`

```
.sidebar {
    background-color: greenyellow;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 300px;
    position: fixed; /* change */
    top: 0; /* change */
    bottom: 0;  /* change */
    left: -100%;    /* change */
}

.sidebar.active {
    background-color: greenyellow;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 300px;
    left: 0;    /* change */
```

```js
const sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar')
const faBars = document.querySelector(".fa-bars")
const faTimes = document.querySelector(".fa-times")

const active = () => sidebar.classList.toggle("active");

faBars.addEventListener("click", active);
faTimes.addEventListener("click", active);
```

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: greenyellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: greenyellow;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -100%;
}

.sidebar.active {
  background-color: greenyellow;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 300px;
  left: 0;
}

.fa-bars,
.fa-times {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="navbar">
  <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It did help me! Thank you so much!